# Created nested/recursive list

Tags: python, list

How can I create a list recursively?

**I have this list:**

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'new', 'c', 'd', 'new', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'fin', 'f', 'fin', 
     'g', 'l', 'new', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'fin', 'j']
```

**The expected output is:**

```
r = ['a', 'b', ['c', 'd', ['z', 'x', 'c'] 'f'], 'g', 'l', ['z', 'x', 'c'] 'j']
```

**What I have tried so far:**

```
def asd(l, index=0):
    r = []
    for i in l[index:]:
        index += 1
        if i == 'new':
            i, index = asd(l, index)
        r.append(i)
        if i == 'fin':
            return r
    return r, index

r, index = asd(l)
```

I cannot understand how to make it work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: How often can new and fin appear? Can new and fin be nested?

Comment: @timgeb yes, it can be nested an indefinite number of times

Comment: @KuskoAndrew in this case, please make a more complete example.

Comment: You need to bypass all the elements in the recursive call, so `for i in l[index:]`cannot work, you have to use a while loop and reuse the `index` return.

Comment: expected should be `['a', 'b', ['c', 'd', ['z', 'x', 'c'], 'f'], 'g', 'l', ['z', 'x', 'c'], 'j']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a stack instead and go through the list and using it:

```
def parse(l):
    stack = [[]]

    for i in l:
        if i == "new":
            stack.append([])
        elif i == "fin":
            pop = stack.pop()
            stack[-1].append(pop)
        else:
            stack[-1].append(i)

    return stack[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a non-recursive solution that can create your list, parsing in one pass without any need for costly `index()` operations:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'new', 'c', 'd', 'new', 'f', 'fin', 'g', 'fin', 'j']

rv = []

curr = [rv]  # things are always added to the last element if not 'fin' or 'new'

for elem in l:
    if elem == "new":
        # create a new list, put it at end of curr 
        curr.append([])
        # add that list to the one before
        curr[-2].append(curr[-1])
    elif elem == "fin":
        # done, remove from curr
        curr.pop() 
    else:
        curr[-1].append(elem)

print(rv)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', ['c', 'd', ['f'], 'g'], 'j']
```

---

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'new', '1', '2', '3', 'fin', 'c', 'new', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'fin',]
```

leads to

```
['a', 'b', ['1', '2', '3'], 'c', ['x', 'y', 'z']]
```

You need to foolproof it against unbalanced / incorrect `new`/`fin`'s

---

Edited to make it more concise after Matthieu's comment.

Comment: @PatrickArtner YES! totally what I am trying to do!  Thank you, sir!

Comment: This works too. If someone trying to figure out how it works, read about the inheritance of dictionaries and variables in python.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a straight forward recursive solution, using a `deque` as a stack data structure from which you can `popleft` the leftmost element in O(1).

**Algorithm**

```
from collections import deque

def nest(lst):
    return _nest(deque(lst))

def _nest(deq):
    result = []

    while deq:
        x = deq.popleft()
        if x == 'fin':
            break
        elif x == 'new':
            result.append(_nest(deq))
        else:
            result.append(x)

    return result
```

**Tests**

```
tests = [
    [],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 'new', 3, 4, 'fin', 5],
    [1, 2, 'new', 3, 4, 'fin', 5, 6, 'new', 7, 'fin'],
    ['new', 'fin', 'new', 'fin', 'new', 'new', 'fin', 'fin'],
    ['new', 1, 2, 'fin'],
    [1, 2, 3, 'new', 4, 'new', 5, 6, 'fin', 7, 8, 'fin', 9, 10, 'new', 11, 'fin', 12, 13]
]

for test in tests:
    print(nest(test))
```

**Output**

```
[]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, [3, 4], 5]
[1, 2, [3, 4], 5, 6, [7]]
[[], [], [[]]]
[[1, 2]]
[1, 2, 3, [4, [5, 6], 7, 8], 9, 10, [11], 12, 13]
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursive alternative :

```
def asd(l):
    if 'new' in l:
        index_new = l.index('new')
        keyword = 1
        for index_fin,e in enumerate(l[index_new+1:], index_new+1):
            if e == 'new':
                keyword += 1
            elif e == 'fin':
                keyword -=1
            if not keyword:
                break
        return l[:index_new] + [asd(l[index_new+1:index_fin])] + asd(l[index_fin+1:])
    else:
        return l
```

Input :

```
['a', 'b', 'new', 'c', 'd', 'new', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'fin', 'f', 'fin', 
     'g', 'l', 'new', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'fin', 'j']
```

Output :

```
['a', 'b', ['c', 'd', ['z', 'x', 'c'], 'f'], 'g', 'l', ['z', 'x', 'c'], 'j']
```